# how to enable remote webpage access nwjs's node environment

Tags: node-modules, nwjs

I was working on a project which need to figure out whether a webpage is running in nwjs and then do some operation based on it.

Now the page is running on a remote server and I use window.location to jump to it from my webapp. When jump to a outside location, the webpage cannot get nwjs node environment even it is opened in nwjs.

I use node-remote to allow access from all urls in the origin webapp's package.json, it is like this:

```
"single-instance": true,
"node-remote": ["*://*"],
"chromium-args": "--args --touch-events=enabled --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files"
```

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

The special pattern  matches any URL that starts with a permitted scheme.
so since you want to match any website then is best to do this

```
"node-remote": ["<all_urls>"]
```

for chromium arguments that are valid for nw.js you can try [this](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) site